# Probability that an r-subset contains an element from it's set

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> Let $S = \{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7\}$. You choose a uniformly random 3-element subset $X$ of $S$. Thus,
>   each 3-element subset of $S$ has a probability of $1{}/{{7}\choose{3}}$ of being $X$.
>
> Define the event
>   $A =$ “$4$ is an element of $X$”
>
> What is $Pr(A)$?

The answer is $\frac37$.

My guess was ${{6\choose2}}/{{7\choose3}} = \frac{15}{35} =  \frac37$, however I'm not quite sure why ${{6\choose2}}$ actually accounts for an already chosen element of $S$ since all it's doing is counting subsets of size $2$ from $6$. Even though I came up with this answer, I have no idea why it makes sense.

Anyone care to explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it would make more sense if you write out the probability as

$$\frac{{1 \choose 1}{6 \choose 2}}{7 \choose 3}$$

We choose the $4$ to be selected giving the ${1 \choose 1}$

We choose $2$ of the other $6$ numbers to be selected giving the $6 \choose 2$

Comment: Thanks. Thinking of it as subsets just confuses me. When I think of it in a practical application ie. "How many ways to choose 1 red ball and 2 blue balls from a pack of 7" makes more sense and would lead me to the way you set up your answer.

Answer (score 1):

View it as $$\frac{\binom62 \binom11}{\binom73}= \frac{\binom62 }{\binom73}=\frac37$$

Answer (score 0):

The probability that a uniformly random $k$-element subset of $[n] := \{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ contains a given element of $[n]$ is the same as the probability that a fixed $k$-element subset of $[n]$ contains a uniformly random element $X$ of $[n]$, which is of course $k \times 1/n = k/n$.